# Is it possible to prevent my Windows Phone app from closing?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to prevent my WP7 app from closing? I know how to override the back button, but is it possible to do the same for the start and search buttons? I am aware that preventing it from closing would cause it to fail certification, but this is a personal app that will not be submitted to the store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications can override only Back button.
Both Search & Start buttons are not available for third-party applications.